# What does `python3 ()` do?

Tags: zsh

While trying to execute a `timeit` command on the command line using the python command line interface I accidentally put `.function()` on the outside of the command like so:

```
$ python3 -m timeit '<code>'.function()
```

Rather than the `timeit` command being executed, I was prompted as such:

```
function>
```

Thinking I had entered the python repl I tried to quit with `q`. Yes, I'm aware `quit()` is the correct way to do this. Having returned to the command line, I noticed the error and corrected it like so:

```
$ python3 -m timeit `<code>.function()`
```

I expected this code to execute correctly, but instead I received the following error:

```
python3:7: command not found: q
```

After discussing it with some colleagues, it was suggested that I check which python was being used:

```
$ which python3
python3 () {
    q
}
```

This was not what I was expecting! Normally the result would be `/usr/local/bin/python3`. Through some trial and error I was able to determine that the minimal case to reproduce this is:

```
$ python3 ()
function> q
$
```

Now that the context is out of the way, I have two questions about the behaviour I witnessed:
 1. What exactly does `python3 ()` do?
 2. How do I return execution to its original state in the same terminal window? I'm aware I can open a new terminal window and the original state exists in that window.

Comment: Note that in this context, any question about `which` is a zsh question, not a python question.

Comment: or bash or dash

Comment: @RayWu, no, specifically zsh. In bash or dash, `which` is an external command and has no ability to access shell functions. One would need to run `type python3` or `declare -f python3` to get equivalent output (identifying a function by that name) in bash.

Comment: I've updated the tags to indicate this is related to zsh, thank you everyone for the clarification!

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `foo ()` is used in POSIX-compliant shells (such as bash, dash, and zsh) to define a function. Your entire snippet defines a function called `python3` and executes the command `q` when it's ran. You can bypass shell functions and aliases using the `command` command: `command -p python3 myfile.py`

To remove the function from the current shell process, you can use `unset -f python3`. If it keeps coming back after starting new shells, then it's likely defined in one of you shell initialization files.

Comment: It's not accurate to claim that zsh is POSIX-compliant; it does not even *attempt* to be POSIX-compliant (except when running in `sh` compatibility mode).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's true and bash is not fully POSIX-compliant either. Is there a better term for grouping those shells together?

Comment: The only place I know of offhand where bash is noncompliant (as opposed to putting extensions in undefined space) is its `echo` implementation (when `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags are not both active). That's much, *much* narrower than, say, not implementing POSIX-defined word-splitting rules. Frankly, I don't consider zsh part of the family at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You don't count "running in `sh` compatibility mode" as an attempt at being POSIX-compliant? That said, the answer could simply say that `foo ()` is POSIX-compliant syntax for defining a function, without addressing any other aspect of the shell in question.

Comment: An important point, though, is that `zsh` extends the function-definition syntax to allow multiple function names in the same definition.  The OP's typo would also have defined functions named `-m`, `timeit`, and `<code>.function`.